# lambda上でheadlesschromeを使ってseleniumを動かそうとするとエラーになる

Tags: python, selenium

マルチポストです。
https://teratail.com/questions/375966

teratailでも回答を募りましたが、
解決に至らなそうなのでこちらでも投稿させていただきます。

lambda上でheadlesschromeを使ってseleniumで操作したいのですが、
上手くいきません。

環境構築はこちらを参考にしました。
バージョン等もこちらと同じです。
https://qiita.com/ichihara-development/items/5e61c3424b3176bc6096

ローカルでは動作しているのですが、
lambda上で実行しようとするとエラーが出ます。

send_keysメソッドが動作していない（？）様に見えるのですが。。

ちなみにローカルはPython 2.7.16で、
lambdaはPython 3.7です。

色々と調べた際、
chrome-driverのバージョンが古いせいでset_keysが対応しないという記事をいくつか見かけましたが、
現状headless-chrominiumのバージョンが最新のchromeのバージョンに追いついていないので、
対応させる事は不可能なのでしょうかね。。
（ローカルで動作するchromeのバージョンは最新なので、chrome-driverのバージョンと合っていて動作する？）

ローカルのPythonのバージョンをlambda側と合わせた3系（3.7.3）に切り替えて実行しましたが、
ローカルでは上手く動作しました。

何か分かる方いれば宜しくお願いします。

エラーメッセージ

```
Test Event Name
selenium

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'send_keys'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 39, in lambda_handler\n    driver.find_element_by_name(\"user_password\").send_keys(\"XXXXXX\")\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: XXX Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 39, in lambda_handler
    driver.find_element_by_name("user_password").send_keys("XXXXXX")
END RequestId: XXX
REPORT RequestId: XXX    Duration: 39112.18 ms    Billed Duration: 39113 ms    Memory Size: 256 MB    Max Memory Used: 256 MB    Init Duration: 301.10 ms

Request ID
a68d20b9-adcd-48a9-ac2a-3a031fcae879
```

コード（Python）

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import requests
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--single-process")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--homedir=/tmp")
    options.binary_location = "/opt/headless/python/bin/headless-chromium"

    #ブラウザの定義
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        "/opt/headless/python/bin/chromedriver",
        options=options
    )


    # 対象サイトに移動
    driver.get('https://test')

    time.sleep(3)

    # ユーザーネーム
    driver.find_element_by_name("user_id").send_keys("XXXXXX")

    # パスワード
    driver.find_element_by_name("user_password").send_keys("XXXXXX")

    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

> chrome-driverのバージョンが古いせいでset_keysが対応しないという記事をいくつか見かけましたが、

環境構築で参考にしたというQiitaの記事のheadless-chromium, chromedriverのバージョンと、
ローカルのheadless-chromium, chromedriverのバージョンと比較してみてください。

Qiitaの記事では、v1.0.0-37のheadless-chromiumと、2.37のchromedriver_linux64のダウンロードが解説されていました。

> $ curl -SL https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-37/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip > headless-chromium.zip

> $ curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip

ですが、そのリポジトリにあるheadless-chromiumは、v1.0.0-57がありました。
https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/

chromedriverももっと新しいバージョンが出ています。
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: headless-chromiumとchromedriverのバージョンを合わせないとエラーになってしまうんですよね。。headless-chromiumにchromedriverの最新の97はないので、headless-chromiumの現状の最新88とchromedriverの88を合わせると「Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /opt/headlessDir/headless-chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)」と出て調べてると、chromedriverのバージョンをあげた方が良いといった情報が出てきます。つんでますかね。。

Answer (score 0):

私も同様の事象に遭遇しましたが、以下URLを参考に

```
options.add_experimental_option("w3c", True)
```

を設定したらうまくいきました。
全く同じ事象かどうかはわかりませんが、ご参考まで。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582816/python-selenium-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-get-attribute

> So, it's another option that could lead to this error. You can fix it by removing it or changing its value to True.